# Accessing files without installing Dropbox from Linux OS installed parellelly in Windows7

Tags: dropbox

I have installed Dropbox in Windows 7. Also, installed Ubuntu Linux 14.04 in parallel. Through online login to Dropbox account allows access to files in Dropbox. However, to work with the files in Dropbox I have to install Dropbox in Linux also. This require additional space in the same PC. So, is it possible to access and work with files in Dropbox@Windows7 without installing Dropbox in Ubuntu (which is installed in the same PC parelelly)?.

Comment: Depends what you mean by access and work.

You can access windows disks in linux, you just need to map it correctly. Then you can do whatever you want with files. But dropbox magic will not work until you load windows again.

Comment: @VladimirM Thanks a lot. I am able to access and edit the files. If I make changes in the files will those changes be synchronized in Dropbox (all other machines)?

Comment: Only when you bootup from windows again, since it is dropbox app that does syncing. What you may do is to deploy dropbox on both windows and linux, but point them to the same data folder. Still there could be some problems with text files, as windows and linux are not treating line endings the same way. So if a file was synchronized in windows, it will have windows endings, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks again @VladimirM I got the answer. Could you please post these comments as an answer so that I can check it as an "accepted answer"?

Comment: ok. I did. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access windows disks in linux, you just need to map it correctly. Then you can do whatever you want with files. But dropbox magic will not work until you load windows again.

Only when you bootup from windows again, since it is dropbox app that does syncing. What you may do is to deploy dropbox on both windows and linux, but point them to the same data folder. Still there could be some problems with text files, as windows and linux are not treating line endings the same way. So if a file was synchronized in windows, it will have windows endings, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could configure a remote filesystem on a USB-Stick so both your systems can access on it and you have a directory where dropbox stores the files.

Look here: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox/Idea-Portable-Dropbox-folder-on-flash-drive/idi-p/122804